# pdfkit—content is shrinking to the top left corner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdfkit

I have some code that generates a certificate PDF, but recently the certificate is small and in the top left corner. How do I get it to fill the PDF page?

Here are my settings:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    disable_smart_shrinking: true,
    page_width: '84.02cm',
    page_height: '118.8cm',
    margin_bottom: 0,
    margin_top: 0,
    margin_left: 0,
    margin_right: 0,
    orientation: 'Landscape'
  }
end
```

If I set the dpi, then that changes the size of the content, but there's no easy way to get it to fill the page, I'd have to try ~50 times to get it right (and it takes a while to generate each pdf). I'm hoping there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just brute-forcing the ideal dpi, and set it in the settings:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.default_options = {
    encoding: 'UTF-8',
    disable_smart_shrinking: true,
    dpi: 384,
    page_width: '84.02cm',
    page_height: '118.8cm',
    margin_bottom: 0,
    margin_top: 0,
    margin_left: 0,
    margin_right: 0,
    orientation: 'Landscape'
  }
end
```

It wasn't fun, and I'm still keen for better ways to fix this issue. Basically, the CSS specified the width and height of the content in px, not %. PDFKit was specifying the page dimensions in cm, so the shrinking happened when the dpi changed (there must have been an update which changed the default dpi, which is why suddenly things changed for my project).